# How to display the content of <img> tag inside a canvas?

Tags: image, html5-canvas, javascript-framework

The page has an `<img>` tag and a canvas element.
The image inside the `<img>` is cropped and is manipulated using the loupe.
How can the cropped content of the image be displayed inside the canvas.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have an `<img>` tag with id of `image`. You can obtain the image reference by using the `getElementById` method. Something like the following:

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");
```

Then using the HTML5 [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) method you can draw the image content into the canvas.
The code should look like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') // reference to canvas element
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // get the canvas context;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); //draw image into canvas;
```

Comment: Image willn't be cross-origin. You can't fetch it if its from another site

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off with this (over the original answer by easimov), which waits until the image has loaded first. If the image hasn't loaded, it won't be drawn on the canvas. It assumes that img is your image tag:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') // reference to canvas element
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // get the canvas context;

img.onload = function ()
{
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); //draw image into canvas;
}
```

Comment: Whether the image is loading or is already loaded does not matter. What matters is transferring the content of image tag to a canvas, which is what the most important part "drawImage(...)" does.

Comment: If the image hasn't loaded yet (eg you have a slow connection) it won't be drawn if you call drawImage(). By using the images onload event you can be sure that it has loaded.